# How to update the the style for frame size in UIDocumentPickerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

In my app, the frame size of my UIDocumentPickerViewController always full screen as the following picture and the following code. However, I find there is a different frame size for the UIDocumentPickerViewController but I don't know how to get the effect as the second picture. Does anyone know how to get the effect?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_q_kfIIYA0d0KcT7NyPpFb6Q1vymU-lb/view?usp=sharing

```
- (void)btnPressDown {
    NSLog(@"Press Down QQ");
     [self showDocumentPickerInMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
}
- (void)showDocumentPickerInMode:(UIDocumentPickerMode)mode {
    NSLog(@"showDocumentPickerInMode QQ");
    UIDocumentPickerViewController *picker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc]     initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.data"] inMode:mode];
    picker.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/177W-O0eJmePhLfS8ifGlw9n3jj26FDn9/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set presentation style. The presentation style determines how a modally presented view controller is displayed onscreen.
 "picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;"

```
- (void)showDocumentPickerInMode:(UIDocumentPickerMode)mode {
    UIDocumentPickerViewController *picker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc]     initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.data"] inMode:mode];
    picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    picker.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Thats it :)